# Get a case's milestone using Fogbugz API

Tags: fogbugz-api

Is there any way to determine what milestone a case is under?

I have looked through the API and the case XML structure and there does not seem to be any way to match up cases and milestones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a work around.

Get all milestones in the project.
Do a search - 'status:Active milestone:"Milestone 1" project:"72"'

Returns a list of all cases with that milestone.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you couldn't do this before, but if you look at the API, you can specify the columns you want when a query gets returned.

So if you want the milestone the case is under, just do this query:

```
cmd=search&q=<case number>&cols=sFixFor,ixFixFor
```

This will return the milestone name as well as the milestone id.